# Amazon S3 not caching images

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm using the Amazon S3 PHP Class to upload images, but the cache headers aren't being set.  Here's the call I'm using.

```
$s3->putObjectFile(
    $image_location,
    "bucketname",
    $image_file_name,
    S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ,
    array(
        "Cache-Control" => "max-age=315360000",
        "Expires" => gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s T", strtotime("+5 years"))
    )
);
```

The header response I'm getting for the uploaded image is:

```
Date: Tue, 04 Oct 2011 04:21:09 GMT
x-amz-request-id: B6BAAAAD9B460160
Content-Length: 34319
x-amz-id-2: Oxxx1hIG2nNKfff3vgH/xx/dffF59O/7a1UWrKrgZlju2g/8WvTcBpccYToULbm
Last-Modified: Tue, 04 Oct 2011 04:19:20 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
ETag: "4846afffbc1a7284fff4a590d5acd6cd"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not familiar with the [Amazon S3 PHP Class](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class) but a quick look at the [documentation](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation) reveals that the `putObjectFile` method is depreciated and you should use `putObject` instead.

```
<?php

    // PUT with custom headers:
    $put = S3::putObject(
        S3::inputFile($file),
        $bucket,
        $uri,
        S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ,
        array(),
        array( // Custom $requestHeaders
            "Cache-Control" => "max-age=315360000",
            "Expires" => gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s T", strtotime("+5 years"))
        )
    );
    var_dump($put);

?>
```

---

But why not consider using the official [Amazon SDk for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/)?

You would use `create_object` to upload a file. The [official docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/create_object) have some good examples:

```
// Instantiate the class
$s3 = new AmazonS3();

$response = $s3->create_object('my-bucket', 'üpløåd/î\'vé nøw béén üpløådéd.txt', array(
    'fileUpload' => 'upload_me.txt',
    'acl' => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC,
    'contentType' => 'text/plain',
    'storage' => AmazonS3::STORAGE_REDUCED,
    'headers' => array( // raw headers
        'Cache-Control' => 'max-age',
        'Content-Encoding' => 'gzip',
        'Content-Language' => 'en-US',
        'Expires' => 'Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT',
    ),
    'meta' => array(
        'word' => 'to your mother', // x-amz-meta-word
        'ice-ice-baby' => 'too cold, too cold' // x-amz-meta-ice-ice-baby
    ),
));

// Success?
var_dump($response->isOK());
```

Comment: Spot on! Thank you very much.  Didn't realize I was using something depreciated, guess that's what happens when you blindly follow a tutorial online without checking its post date.

Answer (score 1):

`Cache-Control` or `Expires` headers are to be sent from server to client to instruct client on caching of the data. In your case, you have client sending those headers to server which has no meaning. I believe that you intention is to send headers to S3 and then you expect them to be provided by S3 when another client asks for the file. This is not supported, I believe.

However, S3 provides `ETAg` and `Last-Modified` headers that should be sufficient for most practical purposes as there is hardly any reason for your client to redownload the file unless it's updated in S3 (in this case `ETag` and `Last-Modified` will change).

Comment: Those headers are sent so Amazon knows what headers to send back to the client when the client requests that specific image, I know they're not meant to go to the server as headers, but as meta-data.

Comment: Also, thanks for the ETag and Last-Modified idea, I'll look into it

Answer (score 1):

`S3::putObjectFile` does not accept Request Headers. The argument you are looking at is [Meta Headers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata) which is not quite the same thing.

`S3::putObjectFile` is just a wrapper around `S3::putObject` anyway so the following will work just fine

`$s3->putObject(
    S3::inputFile($image_location),
    "bucketname",
    $image_file_name,
    S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ,
    array(), // meta headers
    array(   // request headers
        "Cache-Control" => "max-age=315360000",
    )
);`