# How can I reduce my data transfer cost? Amazon S3 --> Cloudflare --> Visitor

Tags: php, amazon-s3, caching, cloudflare

I recently started using Amazon S3 to serve images to my visitors since this will reduce the server load. Now, there is a new problem: Today I looked into my AWS billings. I noticed that I have a huge bill waiting for me - there has been a total of 4TB AWS Data Transfer in 20 days.

Obviously this is because the high amount of outgoing Amazon S3 traffic (to Cloudflare which then serves it to the visitors). Now I should to reduce the amount of requested files by setting a Cache header (since Cloudflare's Crawler will respect that). I have modified my code like this:

```
$s3->putObjectFile($path, $bucket , 'images/'.$id.'.jpg', S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
```

to

```
$s3->putObjectFile($path, $bucket , 'images/'.$id.'.jpg', S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ, array('Cache-Control' => 'public,max-age=31536000'));
```

Still, it does not work. Cloudflare does not respect the Cache because the Cache-Control does not show up as "Cache-Control" in the Header but instead as "x-amz-meta-cachecontrol". Cloudflare ignores this.

Does anyone have an easy solution for this?

**TL;DR:** I have more or less the same problem as this guy: http://support.bucketexplorer.com/topic734.html (that was in 2008)

**EDIT:** I have stumbled upon this: [Amazon S3 not caching images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643295/amazon-s3-not-caching-images) but unfortunately that solution does not work for me.

**EDIT 2:** Turns out it didn't work because I was using an old version of the "Amazon S3 class". I updated and the code works now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are getting "x-amz-meta-cachecontrol", it is likely you are not setting the headers correctly.  It might just be the exact way you are doing it in your code.  This *is* supposed to work.   I am deducing this is php using Amazon S3 PHP Class?

Try this:

```
$s3->putObject(file_get_contents($path), $bucket, $url, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ, array(), array('Cache-Control' => 'max-age=31536000, public'));
```

In the [S3 PHP docs](http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/documentation) `putObjectFile` is listed under Legacy Methods:

```
putObjectFile (string $file, 
               string $bucket, 
               string $uri, 
               [constant $acl = S3::ACL_PRIVATE], 
               [array $metaHeaders = array()], 
               [string $contentType = null])
```

Compare to this:

```
putObject (mixed $input, 
           string $bucket, 
           string $uri, 
           [constant $acl = S3::ACL_PRIVATE], 
           [array $metaHeaders = array()], 
           [array $requestHeaders = array()])
```

You need to set cache-control as a **request** header, but appears that there is no way to set request headers with `putObjectFile`, only meta headers.  You have to use `putObject` and give it an empty array for meta headers and then another array with the request headers (including cache-control).

You can also try some of the other working examples I have listed below.

See also:

[How to set the Expires and Cache-Control headers for all objects in an AWS S3 bucket with a PHP script](http://www.laurencegellert.com/2012/07/how-to-set-the-expires-and-cache-control-headers-for-all-objects-in-an-aws-s3-bucket-with-a-php-script/) (php)

[Updating caching headers for Amazon S3 and CloudFront](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19687)  (python)

[Set cache-control for entire S3 bucket automatically (using bucket policies?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435334/set-cache-control-for-entire-s3-bucket-automatically-using-bucket-policies)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html?r=5225

Comment: I figured out why it didn't work. Turns out I was using an old version of the "Amazon S3 PHP Class". I updated and used your suggested code, and now the new files have a Cache-Control set. Great!

I will also look into your second link to set all the Cache-Control headers for the files that are already in the bucket.

This should solve all my problems. Thanks for everything!

Comment: @Jonas: Were you able to reduce your data transfer following this approach ?.. I know its quite long.. but I am in your boat now.

Answer (score 1):

You can now. Go to s3 bucket. Open the file and set property

[image: Aws console]