# Laravel AWS S3 Storage image cache

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, cache-control, laravel-storage

I have Laravel based web and mobile application that stores images on AWS S3 and I want to add cache support because even small number of app users produce hundreds and sometimes thouthands of GET requests on AWS S3.

To get image from mobile app I use GET request that is being handled by code like this

```
public function showImage(....) {
  ...
  return Storage::disk('s3')->response("images/".$image->filename);
}
```

On the next image you can see response headers that I receive. Cache-Control shows no-cache so I assume that mobile app won't cache this image.

[image]

1. How can I add cache support for this request? Should I do it?
2. I know that [Laravel Documentaion suggests caching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#caching) for Filestorage - should I implement it for S3? Can it help to decrease GET requests count of read files from AWS S3? Where can I find more info about it.

Comment: I'm still new to using S3, but it sounds like the caching should be set in AWS. It looks like you might be able to set this for an entire S3 bucket: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29280730/3103434

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use a temporary URL as described here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-urls

Then use the Cache to store it until it is expired:

```
$value = Cache::remember('my-cache-key', 3600 * $hours, function () use ($hours, $image) {
    $url = Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl(
        "images/".$image->filename, now()->addMinutes(60 * $hours + 1)
    ); 
});
```

Whenever you update the object in S3, do this to delete the cached URL:

```
Cache::forget('my-cache-key');
```

... and you will get a new URL for the new object.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CDN service like CloudFlare and set a cache header to let CloudFlare keep the cache for a certain amount of time.

```
$s3->putObject(file_get_contents($path), $bucket, $url, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ, array(), array('Cache-Control' => 'max-age=31536000, public'));
```

This way, files would be fetched once by CloudFlare, stored at their servers, and served to users without requesting images from S3 for every single request.

See also: 
[How can I reduce my data transfer cost? Amazon S3 --> Cloudflare --> Visitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881692/how-can-i-reduce-my-data-transfer-cost-amazon-s3-cloudflare-visitor) 
[How to set the Expires and Cache-Control headers for all objects in an AWS S3 bucket with a PHP script](http://www.laurencegellert.com/2012/07/how-to-set-the-expires-and-cache-control-headers-for-all-objects-in-an-aws-s3-bucket-with-a-php-script/)